# Ant returns old ant version

Tags: java, ant, build

i removed all ant related environment variables and then setting path to new ..\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin in cmd window. I got only old version while executing ant -version.
Apache Ant version 1.6.2 compiled on August 5 2004

What is the issue?

In environment variables, am setting JAVACMD to jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe.

Comment: did you open a new command prompt? can you run `echo %ANT_HOME%` and `echo  %PATH%`. change %% after and before if you are on *nix/mac and add $ in the front.

Comment: >ant -version
Apache Ant version 1.6.2 compiled on August 5 2004
>echo %ANT_HOME%
C:\Users\windows\Downloads\apache-ant-1.9.3

Comment: path as well please?

Comment: .C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;E:\apache-maven-3.0.1\bin;C:\Users\sivaramans\Downloads\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin;

Comment: Have you set _classpath_ environment variable as well to include _%ANT_HOME%\lib_

Answer (score 0):

After change the environment variable on Windows you need close and reopen the command prompt Window. In Linux, you need to reload .bash_profile: "$>. .bash_profile"

Check the "path" variable, maybe it contain the old Ant path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Windows. Then I found out that the `ant.jar` file being used when running `ant` wasn't the one in `%ANT_HOME%\lib` but instead was located in `%USER_HOME%\.ant\`

You can find out what file is being used by running `ant -diagnostics`. You will find a lot of useful information. Hope this helps.